# iOS PWA suppress Toolbar

Tags: ios, angular, progressive-web-apps

I've written a simple Angular PWA, that I have added on my iPhone to the Homescreen. To remove the Safari Toolbar, I have already included in my index.html:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

See Image "1", the Toolbar is gone. The Problem is: when I hit the "Start"-Button on Image 1, the Angular App routes to a new Component (the URL changes from https://example.com/foo to https://example.com/foo/bar), and some other Toolbar pops up (see Image "2").

**Is there any way to prevent iOS from showing this Toolbar at Image 2?** Thank you!

Image 1:

[image: First Screen, Toolbar OK]

Image 2:

[image: Second Screen, Toolbar pops up]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find a solution myself:

It seems like iOS shows this Toolbar if the Host or Path of a URL changes, so I checked if it also takes the URL Fragment (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax) into account, and it does not! Yay!

So my solution for an Angular-based Webapp is to configure Hash-based LocationStrategy like this in your AppModule:

```
import {HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy} from "@angular/common";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
   ...
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This way no Toolbar pops up, if I change the Route in Angular.

Comment: This solution seems to work but after a while the Done button DOES appear again in some cases. Is there another way besides the solution of Hash-based LocationStrategy?
This was not an issue on iOS 12.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well when creating a PWA in Angular 8. The solution was

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })]
})
```

in my `app-routing.module.ts`